# c++: strange syntax in what() method of std::exception

Tags: c++, exception

When i am inheriting from `std::exception` in order to define my own exception type, i need to override the `what()` method, which has the following signature:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

This definitely looks strange to me, like if there were two method names in the signature. Is this some very specific syntax, like with pure virtual methods, e.g.:

```
virtual int method() const = 0;
```

or is this a feature, that could somehow be used in another context, too? And if so, for what could it be used?

Comment: Em... That's pretty usual syntax. What exactly drags your attention?

Comment: just wondering what the throw() at the end of the line does. i have never seen this anywhere else until now, as i am implementing my own exception type for the first time.

Comment: And hopefully you will never ever see it again.

Comment: @pmr i am wishfully waiting for the new standard ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called `exception specifications`. The `throw()` doesn't allow any exception to be thrown from inside this method `throw(int)` would only allow exceptions of type `int` to be thrown.

Exception specifications will be dropped in C++0x. [This](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) gives a very good explanation of the reasons.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what i wanted to know :) hard to find something on the net if you don't know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

`what()` is a virtual constant method that returns pointer to `const char` and must not throw any exception. Not very strange method declaration :)

Comment: the throw() is a list of all the exception types `what` might throw. And since there's nothing in the list, it doesn't throw anything. Exception lists are generally considered horrible so rarely appear in the wild. And they're going away, so they will become even rarer.